# Why is $\inf_{m\geq n} X_m = \cap_{m\geq n} X_m$?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Why is $\inf_{m\geq n} X_m = \bigcap_{m\geq n} X_m$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Because the intersection is the greatest lower bound (inf) with respect to the subset ordering between sets. // \bigcap would look better than \cap.

Comment: is that in the context of limsup? If not, can you take the infimum of a sequence sets or the intersection of random variables? :|

Comment: @BrianO could you elaborate more on that please? I've also read that on wikipedia, but I could not understand it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\inf$ means greatest lower bound *with respect to* [w.r.t.] *some ordering*. In the identity you ask about, that ordering is $\subseteq$.

1. For each $m'\ge n$, $\bigcap_{m\ge n} X_m \subseteq X_{m'}$. In other words, the intersection of  $\{X_m\mid m\ge n\}$ is a lower bound w.r.t. $\subseteq$ of every member of that set.
2. For any set $W$, if $W\subseteq X_m$ for all $m\ge n$ — that is, if $W$ is a lower bound w.r.t. $\subseteq$ — then $W\subseteq \bigcap_{m\ge n} X_m$. In other words, the intersection is the greatest lower bound w.r.t. $\subseteq$.

These two statements show that 
$$
\inf\limits_{m\ge n} X_m = \bigcap\limits_{m\ge n} X_m \tag{$\mathbf{Note\colon \inf = \sideset{}{^{\subseteq}}\inf}$}
$$

This identity holds quite generally for arbitrary families of sets, when $\inf$ is taken to mean $glb$ w.r.t. set inclusion.

---

**Addendum**: "What if the $X_n$ are functions?"
whose domains are all subsets of some common superset $A$, say. "When I think about the case where $\forall a\in A \, X_i(a)\ne X_j(a), i\ne j$, I tend to think that even though the lim inf [may] exist, the intersection of the $X_i$ is always the empty set... Am I wrong?"

You are right. The intersection of two functions is their restriction to elements that they agree on:
$$
f\cap g = \{(x,y)\mid x\in dom(f)\cap dom(g) \text{ and } f(x) = g(x) = y\},
$$
so if they agree on nothing, their intersection is empty.

Again, it's essential to be clear about *which ordering $\inf$ is relative to*. $\inf$ with respect to $\subseteq$ is quite different from $\inf$ with respect to $\le$ on $\Bbb R$, the more common use. $\lim \inf$ is with respect to the latter ordering.

As in the (Note:) on the identity displayed above, let's explicitly superscript $\inf$ with the intended ordering. If the $X_m$ are real-valued functions, then $\lim \inf$ makes sense, but the $\inf$ in question is $\sideset{}{^{\le}}\inf$, not $\sideset{}{^{\subseteq}}\inf$.

To spell it out: If the $X_m$ are functions, it's still true that
$$
\sideset{}{^{\subseteq}}\inf\limits_{m\ge n} X_m = \bigcap\limits_{m\ge n} X_m ,
$$
but in general, equality does *not* hold for $\inf$ with respect to $\le$:
$$
\sideset{}{^{\le}}\inf\limits_{m\ge n} X_m \ne \bigcap\limits_{m\ge n} X_m .
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What happens if we think of $X_n$ as a function?

Comment: You already are thinking of it as a function, it is a function, namely, $n\mapsto X_n$. Aka an "indexed family of sets".

Comment: What I meant was if $X_n(\omega)$ was a function in omega, what would happen? Is it still valid and how?

Comment: Oh ok, I considered that interpretation but thought it less likely. Nothing is changed by the $X_n$ being functions.

Comment: So, yes it's still valid. "and how"? I'm not sure how to respond. Functions are just sets, of ordered pairs, and $\subseteq$ makes sense for them too.

Comment: Yes, it would seem that way. However, when I think about the case when $\forall_{\omega \in \Omega} X_i(\omega)\neq X_j(\omega)$, and $X_n \rightarrow X$, I tend to think that even though the lim inf exists, the intersection of $X_i$ is always the empty set... Am I wrong?

Comment: You're right. The intersection of two functions is their restriction to elements that they agree on, so if they agree on nothing, their intersection is empty. Mind you, then, $\inf$ *with respect to $\subseteq$* is quite different from $\inf$ with respect to $\le$ on $\Bbb R$, the more common use. *That* $\inf$ of functions does not equal the intersection of those functions. So if *that* is what you really meant by "what if they're functions", well, this really is what I mean in response. Again I will stress: it's essential to be clear about which ordering $\inf$ is relative to.

Comment: Brian, would it be too much to ask if you could add this last comment of yours to your answer. It would make it much more complete. Either way, thanks for your help. ;)

Comment: I took you up on your suggestion.

Comment: You're welcome.